# QGIS: startup.py executed twice?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

To test something I have a very simple `startup.py` file in my .qgis/python folder:

```
import qgis
qgis.utils.iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()

print "Welcome chump"
```

Python console launches fine, `Welcome chump` consistently prints out twice. Why is this?

Comment: Could you open an issue report for this with details about the affected QGIS version? The next release is around the corner and only fixed bugs are good bugs :) https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn yes will do, I'll just have to wait until I'm back at the office to get full info on version number etc. It appears then that this is a genuine bug?

Comment: It does not sound like proper behavior to me and deserves being investigated

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn FYI: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/15189

Comment: FYI: Fixed in QGIS 2.16

Answer (score 2):

I’m facing the same problem.
I have not found a real solution, but I found out, that in content of the build in variable `__name__` changes. It is “qgis.user” one time and “startup” the other. So you can work around the problem by:

```
import qgis
if __name__=="qgis.user":
    qgis.utils.iface.actionShowPythonDialog().trigger()
    print "Welcome chump"
```

Answer (score 1):

It was a bug that was fixed - see https://issues.qgis.org/issues/15189